# Drupal view module, add taxonmy class to list item

Tags: css, drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm building a site in Drupal 7. I'm using the view module to query the kind of content I want to display in a list. I have a view that gather the latest content on the site. all pages are  articles content type to which a category is assigned. I need to colour code the different category to help with the navigation. I'm trying to add a custom class to every list item when Drupal aggregate the content in my view, based on the page taxonomy.

In the view module, there is a field where, i believe, it's possible to replace / add a custom class to every item wrapper (row class field).

> You may use field tokens from as per the "Replacement patterns" used in "Rewrite the output of this field" for all fields.

I tried to add the following token to output the class dynamically `[node:field-article-category:vocabulary]`, `[node:field_article_category]`, `[content:field_article_category]` etc...

But it only output something like: `-nodefield-article-category`.

Is it something that's actually doable or did i got it all wroooong?

cheers

---

**update**

if in the row field i add the value `[title]` I get the value of the article title in the class name. I can't seem to find out how I can reference my taxonomy term. I have created a Categories taxonomy (machine name: categories). I tried to just use `[term]`, `[categories]` or `[node:field_article_category]` which is the value used by the PathAuto module to generate the url. but nothing is working. is there a simple name i'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

:(

[field_article_category]

was right under my nose all along .... the replacement values can be found in the `rewrite result > replacement patterns` details element.